# controller in "shahab" directive does not working .(is Null)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have two directive and want to access controller that defined in `hossein`'s directive.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('hossein', function() {
  return {
    restricted: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      name: '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
      console.log(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,", scope.name);
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      var name = $scope.name;
      this.fu = function() {
        return name;
      }
    }
  }
});
app.directive('shahab', function() {
  return {
    restricted: 'A',
    require: '^?hossein',
    scope: {
      name: '=ngName'

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, controll) {
      console.log(",,,,,,,,gfddfdfg,,,,,,,,,,,", controll);
      scope.name = controll.fu();
    }
  }
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="maincontroller">
        <form ng-controller="newcontroller" name="myform" id="form">
            <h2>AngularJS</h2>
            <p>Name:
                <input name="user" type="text" hossein ng-model="name">
            </p>
            <p>Family:
                <input name="famil" type="text" shahab ng-name="">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you missed to add `shahab` directive inside `hossein` directive element

Comment: i  insert require:'^?hossein'

Comment: could you please add your html, how this two directives have been used over there?

Comment: This is not the correct way to what you wanted to achieve..I'd highly recommend to read up on this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate ..

**Side Note** `restricted` option in directive should be `restrict`

Answer (score 1):

You must use **shahab** and **hossein** directives nested, so you can access the outer controller.

```
<hossein ng-model="name">

    <shahab ng-name="">

    </shahab>
</hossein>
```